# Sum of items from two different datasets

Tags: asp.net-mvc, expression, reportviewer

I have two tables and each table has a totals box. I want to get the sum of both totals and place the answer in a textbox. This is kindof what i am looking for in my reporting page:

```
=SUM((Fields!TotalHours.Value, "ActivitySummary")+(Fields!TotalHours.Value, "SchoolActivity"))
```

Comment: We need more information. Does this not work? Is the C#.Net, SSRS, etc?

Comment: @MikeTWebb When i build it throws this message: Error 1 The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox104’ uses an aggregate expression without a scope.  A scope is required for all aggregates used outside of a data region unless the report contains exactly one dataset.

Comment: @MikeTWebb C#.net i am using a reporting page and trying to do this within the report page itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying multiple ways this is what finally worked:

```
Sum(Fields!TotalHours.Value, "ActivitySummary") + Sum(Fields!TotalHours.Value, "SchoolActivity")
```